# Receive ArgumentError during test, but not in development, why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

**UPDATE:** The update action is now being processed as JS (thanks to the option "xhr: true"), however the error message persists... I don't know why it's throwing an error during the test, but NOT when running in development.

I've updated both the title and content of my question to reflect these changes.

**So now I'm at a loss what might be causing this error... Any ideas?**

---

Whenever I try to test the update action for a controller, I receive the following error message:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)`

Here's the spot in the controller that receives the error:

```
def update 
  ...
  # \/ This line causing the error \/
  if @image.update(image_params.except(:image_tags_attributes))
    if image_params[:crop_x].present?
    ...
```

And here is the test I'm running:

```
class ImagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # ....
  test "should add current_user.id to tag related through table after an update action that contains crop parameters" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    patch image_path(@image), params: { image: {
                                          crop_x: 100,
                                          crop_y: 100,
                                          crop_w: 100,
                                          crop_h: 100,
                                          crop_rotation_angle: 0,
                                          image_tags_attributes: {
                                            tag_title_attributes: {
                                              title: @tag_title.title
                                            },
                                            tag_content_attributes: {
                                              content: ""
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }, xhr: true
    assert ImageTagTitle.last.user_id == @user.id
  end
end
```

As far as I can tell, I'm passing everything in for the test in the same manner as I do on the development side so I'm confused what may be causing them to process differently.

Thank you in advance for any help and insights you can offer!

test.log

```
Processing by ImagesController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"image"=>{"crop_x"=>"100", "crop_y"=>"100", "crop_w"=>"100", "crop_h"=>"100", "crop_rotation_angle"=>"0", "image_tags_attributes"=>{"tag_title_attributes"=>{"title"=>"MyTitle1"}, "tag_content_attributes"=>{"content"=>""}}}, "id"=>"249799255"}
```

development.log

```
Processing by ImagesController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IUXYLsxSoD/OYdnm5TH/3jNbaG+7bkwZJL39p/vePkEXrnNk3J+1nrFkgIT3rsQeFmzRdt5kRMO+Vpjo7F5BCg==", "image"=>{"image_tags_attributes"=>{"tag_title_attributes"=>{"title"=>"page number"}, "tag_content_attributes"=>{"content"=>""}}, "crop_x"=>"42.73287586330139", "crop_y"=>"45.58570767432143", "crop_w"=>"123.71134020618558", "crop_h"=>"117.08396046432024", "crop_rotation_angle"=>"0"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Can you include the test in the question? You can pass a format option, but how to do it depends on if its a `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` or if its the old depreciated `ActionDispatch::ControllerTest`.

Comment: Hi @max! Of course! Added the test to the OP. On Rails 5+, the test is headed as `class ImagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`

Comment: @max, the test now processes as JS (thanks to xhr: true), but the error message persists... Now I'm **really** confused! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: is your `@image` an `ActiveRecord` instance ?, is `@image.update` doing something else other than just updating some columns in your database ?, like uploading to S3, or some other process ?. If so, you could have somewhere a `rescue` rescuing an exception and then raising it again and that's why you could be getting a different error than what you would get. If the code is doing something else, try to see if there's a `rescue` and comment it out, that way you'll get the original error.

Comment: Thank you for your help @fanta, sorry I'm just now getting back to you! I got pulled into another direction but I'll definitely refer back to your comment whenever I address it again :)